# Name of scientist who discovered lifesaving drug and chose not to patent it?

Tags: pharmacology

I recall reading about a 20th century scientist who made a life-saving drug that could have patented it and made millions. He chose not to and saved the lives of millions around the globe.

I thought it was [Frederick Banting](http://www.scienceheroes.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=80&Itemid=115) - but it doesn't sound quite right.

None of the others [in this list](http://www.scienceheroes.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=258&Itemid=232) seem quite right.

My question is: **What is the name of scientist who discovered lifesaving drug and chose not to patent it?**

Comment: It's just possible that you are thinking of the failure to patent hybridoma technology. Georges Kohler and Cesar Milstein developed this at the MRC lab in Cambridge, and won a Nobel prize. Milstein was probably philosophically opposed to patenting, but the failure to do so was essentially a bureaucratic decision. It's an interesting story.

Comment: Patenting may not always be for earning profits. Patent also protects an invention form others who intend to make a profit out of it. I don't think any researcher became rich by selling drugs- it is the pharma companies that set high margins between the production and market price and make millions of dollars from other's illnesses (and in most cases the product is **not** developed by their R&D)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dr Jonas Salk or Dr Albert Sabin who did not patent their respective polio vaccines. There are some more such researchers so I am not sure who exactly you are looking for but this would be a start.

Answer (score 2):

You could've been thinking correctly. Banting did patent insulin but felt it was unethical to profit from such a critical drug. He sold the patent for a dollar to a (now nonexistent) pharmaceutical company.